# What is the oldest file in Windows 10 installation?

Tags: windows-10

What file in the Windows 10 installation is the oldest using date last modified as the metric? Do they still have files untouched from the DOS days?

Comment: I could've sworn I saw this question yesterday. Turns out it was on Quora: http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-oldest-piece-of-code-still-in-use-in-the-current-Windows-or-Mac-OS

Comment: Please [note](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."* Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it could be the **moricons.dll** file with lots of icons from the MS-DOS era:

[image: moricons.dll]